# Laravel Sender or From not working as expected

Tags: php, gmail, laravel-5.1, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I have this issue in the laravel 5.1 mail. Though I already assigned a different email, it is still getting the smtp user address. To explain more here are my configs:

**in my .env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=whatiwant@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=myname
MAIL_USERNAME=validgmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

**my code for sending mail**

```
$message->from(getenv('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), getenv('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
$message->sender(getenv('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), getenv('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
$message->to($to, $name)->subject($subj);
```

**in my config/mail**

```
'from' => ['address' => getenv('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => getenv('MAIL_FROM_NAME')],
```

So supposedly when it was sent to the recipient it should show that the sender now will be from "**myname**<**whatiwant@mydomain.com**>" instead it shows "**myname**<**validgmail@gmail.com**>".

PS: In gmail their's an option to Show Original and from there it shows this:

```
Received: from local.com ([my_ip])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id *******
        for <recipient@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1 cipher=**** bits=128/128);
        Tue, 06 Sep 2016 20:25:36 -0700 (PDT)
From: myname <validgmail@gmail.com>
X-Google-Original-From: myname <whatiwant@mydomain.com>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with gmail. It doesn't let you use arbitrary from addresses, though you can predefine a limited number of aliases in gmail prefs. This is mentioned in the PHPMailer docs.

Comment: you're right. sorry about that. I thought it was a laravel problem. Thanks bro :)